# Spring-security using a custom form - authentication does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a custom login for authentication and autohorization using `Spring-Security 4.0.2.RELEASE`. I'm using xml configuration.

This is my `web.xml`:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Authorization with Spring security</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

This is my `spring-security.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/member*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_MEMBER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login 
        login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>

        <logout invalidate-session="true"/>
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="member" password="member" authorities="ROLE_MEMBER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

And this is my login.jsp built using Bootstrap:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>LOGIN - PAOLO</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text" name='j_username'
                class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label> <input
                type="password" name='j_password' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I delete `login-page="/login"` from the `spring-security.xml`, that is using the default login form provided by spring security, the authentication works properly: just admin/admin and member/member are allowed to access. If I use my custom form when I press the submit button a GET request to `/login?j_username=<inserted_username>&j_password=<inserted_password>`launches. 
I don't understand why my authentication does not work with a custom form.

Answer (score 0):

First, add to your form tag an action attribute with the login url, according to your security xml configuration it's '/login' , and add the method attribute with with POST value, because forms are meant to be posted. Like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/login" >
```

It's also recommended to use the spring url tag inside the action attribute, just to be on the safe side, and to make sure we'll populate the correct URL.

Second, you are missing in the security configuration from where to read the user name and password.

```
<form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login" 
    username-parameter="userNameLogin" password-parameter="passwordLogin"/>
```

You should add the username-parameter and the password-parameter attributes to your form-login.

**In your case their values will be j_username and j_password.**